# PhpMyAdmin Table Export ignores timestamp column

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, phpmyadmin

I have noticed of late that when exporting a MySQL table with a TIMESTAMP column, that column is ignored when executing INSERT statement part of Export. What could be the problem? illustration below:

Generated Export CREATE TABLE statement:

```
-- Table structure for table `req_status`
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `req_status`;
CREATE TABLE `req_status` (
  `req_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `change_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Generated Export INSERT statement

```
--
-- Dumping data for table `req_status`
--

INSERT INTO `req_status` (`req_id`, `stat_id`) VALUES
(1, 5),
(2, 5);
```

Comment: Are you using phpMyAdmin to create the export? Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Are you changing any of the export settings from the default? This works fine for me so perhaps there's something situational with your phpMyAdmin configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This was reported as a bug when using MySQL >= 8.0.13. It's supposedly fixed in phpMyAdmin 5.0.1, but I'm using that version and still have this problem so I'm not so sure it was.

https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/15315

You can use mysqldump instead:

```
mysqldump -h [hostname] -u [user] -p [database-name] [tables] > [path-to-dump-file]
```